# Getting different result in calculation of last 30 days and 1 Month sales using DATESINPERIOD() DAX function

Tags: powerbi, dax, analytics

I am calculating last 30 days Sales using the DAX function DATESINPERIOD(). I am getting different result when I am calculating last 30 days Sales & last 1 Month sales. Both the expression should give same result but I am wondering why I am getting different result. For Last 30 Days sales, I am getting result as 233351 whereas for last 1 Month,am getting result as 46693.

```
Last 30 Days Sales(DATESINPERIOD()) = CALCULATE([Total_Sales],DATESINPERIOD(Sales_Data[Date],LASTDATE(Sales_Data[Date]),-30,DAY))
```

[image]

```
Last 1 Month Sales(DATESINPERIOD()) = CALCULATE([Total_Sales],DATESINPERIOD(Sales_Data[Date],LASTDATE(Sales_Data[Date]),-1,MONTH))
```

[image]

Am attaching the dataset also. Can someone please tell me why I am getting different result.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You get different results because these measures arent equivalent.

Dateinperiod for Month return only this:

[image]

You should think about Full periods.You have provided the engine with information that you want to receive days from the last month

Comment: Can someone please elaborate the reason for the change in the sales value obtained from these two functions? I wonder why 30 Days and 1 month sales are not identical when I use same function.

Comment: First, months have different numbers of days, it is not a constant value; DATESINPERIOD, returns the days in a specified period. For a month, it will always be from the 1st of the month (the function does not move us back by a month / or 30 days; it only looks for the beginning of the period).
In your example, DATESINPERIOD, -2, MONTH would return data starting on December 1, 2021.

Comment: Okay, so basically for DATESINPERIOD with -30,Days --> it goes back to 30 days and gives the total sum of sale values. But for DATESINPERIOD with -1,MONTH, it does not go 1 month back instead it checks the 1st Date of the month and gives the total sale value from 1st date of that Month till whatever dates are there. In my dataset, when I am applying -1,MONTH, it is picking up 1st Jan'22 and perform calculation till 6th Jan(last sales date),But when I am applying -30,days, it is picking up the exact 30th day by counting back from 6th Jan(last sales date)and then do the calculation till 6th Jan,